# Which Ubuntu is best for me?

Tags: system-installation, system-requirements, distro-recommendation

I'm looking to learn to code in C and would like your opinion on what would be the best operating system for a laptop.

I have an older 'Dell' laptop, which is very slow, but I've seen reviews that say Ubuntu gave their old Windows PC's a new lease of life.

I'm considering bringing this old one back to life as a dedicated Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Please note that Ask Ubuntu is a question and answer site that focuses on objective and verifiable content. Questions which are mainly opinion-based are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

On the new one choose some of the 16.04 release for better UEFI and hardware support. At the old both 14.04 and 16.04 will be good.

**PERSONAL OPINION**
I use my favorite flavor Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 on both my old **laptop** with 32bit single core celeron CPU/2GB RAM/intergrated GPU and my **desktop** with fx-8150 8-core CPU/8GB RAM/AMD HD 7750 GPU. Just disable the compositor from MATE tweak at the old one and choose compton or compiz for better visual effects at the new one.
If your laptop is too old then go for lubuntu (greate performance but I stop using it because it has several bugs in my opinion) or xubuntu (used it for 2 years and it is very stable, its only a bit lighter than mate, disable the compositor at the old laptop if you choose it).
I hate all Ubuntu-GNOME (with gnome desktop), Kubuntu (with KDE) or Ubuntu (with the default Unity desktop) and I think Ubuntu-MATE has nothing to be jealous of them :P